# Which of the following sets are monoids under addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Which of the following are monoids under addition?

> i) All integers
>
> ii) All even integers
>
> iii) All odd integers
>
> iv) all positive even integers
>
> v) all integers or halves of integers

Refer to answer below for attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) The integers are an Abelian Group under addition, and hence are most certainly a monoid under addition.

ii) The even integers are associative and have the identity $0$

iii) The odd integers do not hold under closure, since there exist $a,b,c$ with $a+b=c$, $a,b\in\Bbb Z_o$ but $c\not\in\Bbb Z_o$.

iv) The positive even integers don't have an identity element. Assume they do, $$2+x=x+2=2$$
$$x+2=2\implies x=2-2=0,0\not\in\Bbb Z^+_e$$ Hence there is no element satisfying the identity relation for $2\in\Bbb Z^+_e$ and hence there is no identity element, e.g. this is not a monoid under addition.

v) All integers and half integers are a monoid under addition since we have an isomorphic mapping $f:\Bbb Z^* \to \Bbb Z$, $f(x)=2x$ which takes this integers and half integers to $\Bbb Z$. Hence this is an Abelian group under addition.

---

Thus only iii and iv are not monoids under addition.

Comment: Looks pretty good.  Note that you could use the same isomorphic mapping from (v) in (ii).  You misused the word "hence" which I fixed.

Comment: Part (iv) is slightly incomplete.  You have not shown that there does not exist an identity element, only that $0$ is not an identity element.

Comment: @Goos Oh thank you, all good points!